# Quick reply in react native gifted chat not showing

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

I have the following setup done in my code, however the quick replies are not showing. Below shown is my state object and render code. [The quick reply is not showing, am i missing something in the code ?    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE1wH.jpg)

```js
state = {
       messages : [
        {
            _id: 1,
            text: 'My message',
            "quickReplies":[
                {
                  "contentType":"text",
                  "title":"Yes",
                  "imageUrl":"http://example.com/img/yes.png"
                },
                {
                  "contentType":"text",
                  "title":"No",
                  "imageUrl":"http://example.com/img/no.png"
                }
              ]
          }],  
    }
```

My Render method is as follows

```js
render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
                <HeaderIconExample color ='#1976d2' title ={"Digital Assistant"} />
                <GiftedChat
                    messages={this.state.messages}
                    onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
                    onQuickReply={quickReply => this.onQuickReply(quickReply)}
                    user={{
                        _id: 1
                    }}
                />
                <KeyboardSpacer />
            </View>
         );
    }
```

However when the app executes, only the text property of the message object is shown. Please see below image for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The format of quick reply is wrong:
[image]

You should change it to something like this

```
  message: [{
     _id: 1,
     text: "text",
     createdAt: new Date(),
     user: user,
     quickReplies: {
         type: 'radio' // or 'checkbox'
         values: [{
             title: "yes"
             value: "yes"
         },{
             title: "no"
             value: "no"
         }]  
      }
}]
```

Comment: not working to me at all, only type radio show